# Why does Jon Snow want to keep this secret from Daenerys?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S07E03 of HBO's *Game of Thrones*, Jon interrupts Ser Davos' speech, preventing him from telling Jon's 'return from death' story. Why does he do so?

Comment: Why does a guy who has come seeking aid from cynical people against an enemy widely believed to be myths and legends of old, want to hide the fact that he was actually killed and resurrected? I wonder why would that be.

Comment: There seems to be more here. Melissandre could have verified it, beforehand, and Daenerys queries Tyrion about it afterward. I think your logic is correct, @Aegon, but you may be trivialising a potentially important plot-point. Many people have asked this question, even written articles on it, so it is mistifying folks.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I did cover the Mel angle, at least based on how view it.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a combination of @Aegon's point and I think Daenerys would take issue with allying with people who would betray and murder their leader. It would jeopardise her opinion of Jon as a competent leader, or her opinion of Northmen (or both), and overcomplicate things.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Night's Watch has never been Northern. It was a tapestry of all seven Kingdoms and still is. Heck even Wildlings serve in NW after defecting

Comment: @Aegon "I did cover the Mel angle", Actually I was only replying to your comments, irrespective of your now existent answer (inexistent ATOW my above comments)

Comment: @Aegon maybe they are selective in their belief of the supernatural. They do believe in evil magic can bring people back to life to be people but not in armies of zombies.

Comment: Thanks for the thought put into the ideal, spoiler-less phrasing here. It's crystal clear what you mean if you're up to speed, but doesn't ruin anything if you're not.  (I often find it hard to nail that balance on GoT posts.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because that makes him and his followers sound like insane/superstitious people.

And he definitely doesn't want to come across as mad given the incredible nature of the task he is about.

Saying that he saw and fought White Walkers is insane enough but at least he can prove it, if Daenerys was to go to North with him.

The dagger in the heart however, He may choose to reveal it afterwards but as of now, he is trying to persuade Daenerys and Tyrion that White Walkers exist and he needs their help to stop them. If he tells that I was dead but then got magically resurrected, that would put an end to all these efforts as Daenerys would dismiss his request as ramblings of a mad man. Imagine some guy walking up to you and saying "Hey, Guess what? I got stabbed in the heart, died and then whoosh, Here I am". What would you make of his mental health?

Even if Melisandre adds her voice to him, Tyrion being the cynical man that he is would suspect foul-play and wonder if Melisandre coming to Dragonstone was indeed a coincidence or unrelated to Jon Snow's arrival<sup>1</sup>. And Daenerys would be pre-disposed to listen to whatever Tyrion said. And if Tyrion decided that Jon was playing at something else here, that would end Jon's hopes of aid. Tyrion and Jon aren't BFFs. They briefly knew each other on a trip and have respect for each other but that's it.

Daenerys has picked up on that bit, I believe she will eventually ask Jon all about it.

---

<sub>1. Since clarification is required on this point, If I were an advisor to Daenerys, I'd have suspected that Jon may have sent Mel himself to persuade Daenerys summon him and then portray him as some sort of resurrected messiah and a good guy for some ulterior motives. Which makes Mel's visit completely planned and in fact one strand in a wider web of plans, which would be unknown to me.
 And whatever is unknown to you, you fear it.</sub>

Comment: "Melisandre coming to Dragonstone was indeed a coincidence or unrelated to Jon Snow's arrival." - But Jon Snow only traveled to Dragonstone at the request of Daenerys, who only got the idea to invite Jon Snow because Melisandre insisted the two should meet, so this part I quoted sounds, to me, confused.

Comment: @GhotiandChips What I am implying is, Targs may have suspected that Mel came to DS, Asked us to summon Jon, And then Jon came. Did he plan it with Mel? I had hoped it would be clear. Evidently not. I'll edit it so that people can pick up on the implication here

Comment: I see, so you are saying that it wouldn't have mattered if Melisandre confirmed it, it might have made things worse for Jon's cause to convince people of his campaign against the dead. I, personally, don't see how this explains why Mel didn't come out of the gate proclaiming her role in his resurrection, advertising the power of R'hllor, unless you claim this, too, was a choice she made to avoid the "madman" label. I think the whole obfuscation of Jon's revival is interesting. It's also odd to me that Jon hasn't had a chat with Sansa about it. Seems The Hound is more realistic that way.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I thought about it but couldn't find any explanation other than that Shireen's death really got to her and she was ashamed to see the two men again or that she reached the same conclusion. But if she had reached the same conclusion, that shouldn't have hampered her from receiving the Northmen at least. Since she didn't do either, I suspect it's a combination of the two.

Comment: @Aegon She states in the episode why she doesn't meet the two men, and it is because of the reason you just said ("ashamed"), however I was more talking about why she didn't preach about her awesome powers, and Jon's revival, during her request to Dany to invite him to Dragonstone (*before* the two men arrive). It seems odd to me that she'd arrive at the conclusion that Daenerys would consider her/them madmen, or that she would guess Tyrion would suspect something. So, I have some reason to think it's at least *interesting* that this whole Jon Snow thing is being kept secret.

Comment: @Aegon but he has a stap wound to prove it.

Comment: @madmada the wound can be self-inflicted, a skin-deep one presented as one which slit his heart. That would be the only logical conclusion for any reasonable person who is unwilling to accept that dead people can be resurrected.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - " don't see how this explains why Mel didn't come out of the gate proclaiming her role in his resurrection" - "We know you were resurrected, Jon Snow."  "How do you know that?"  "She told us.  She's here" (Davos pulls out his sword): "Excuse me, King Jon, I need to take care of something...."

Comment: To me, it makes more sense that she (and Jon) are keeping it secret because it hurts their already precarious PR job of convincing the world of apparent fantasies. That makes a whole lot *more* sense. But the reason hasn't been explicitly stated yet, and I find that motivation interesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63275/discussion-between-poloholeset-and-ghoti-and-chips).

Comment: @GhotiandChips What no one has mentioned, nor answered, is that there ***must*** be some critically important plot point still unrevealed to us which Jon hiding this from Dany somehow furthers. Checkov leaves no loaded guns unfired. The gun didn't go off in Season 7, and there are only 6 episodes left. It could be a million things, even somehow connected to Dany's dream in the House of the Undyong of finding her "dead" husband and familial bliss  beyond the Wall. We just don't know -- but we will, even if it's some last-episode WTF plot twist.

Answer (score 32):

A few reasons:

1. He's already asking her to believe in a threat that most people think is superstitious nonsense. If he makes that claim and also says "Oh, yeah, I was killed and raised from the dead," then he runs the risk of not getting aid because he's dismissed as a total nut-job.
2. It undercuts his credibility as the man "those hard bastards all chose ... to be their leader because they believe in him"..... except those who so distrusted him that they committed mutiny and murder.
3. It undercuts his ability as a competent leader. You can't be less in control of a situation than having a bunch of people use you as a pin cushion. He put himself in a situation where they were able to do that.  One might look at this as an indication that he does not have a firm grasp on what is going on under his command, which might lead one to not devote energy, resources or troops to his cause.
4. He is clearly uncomfortable with the whole thing. He definitely seems to be more fixated, mentally, on the being killed part than being brought back, in terms of time, energy and emotion he devotes to thinking about it. He specifically asked not to be brought back again, if he died in the Battle of the Bastards.  He doesn't know why, if there was any reason, he was brought back. He seems to be someone who, excluded as a bastard (to a certain extent), wants to be accepted as a "regular" guy. He joined the Night's Watch, where they were all supposed to be brothers, equal in all ways, with everyone having a clean slate. He doesn't like being in charge ("I didn't ask for this" "I don't {like what I'm good at})". Being a zombie-King, so to speak, might tend to isolate someone from others and make them unlikely to want to interact...

For many reasons, it's not something he likes to discuss, in general ("I was brutally murdered.  Yeah...."), and it seems like he sees it as potentially a strategic detriment to put it out there early.

Comment: I hadn't thought about points 2 or 3 - interestingly put.

Comment: In fact they are the most important points, as they reveal the possible existence of potential spies.

Comment: Or worse: "Hey, I need your help to kill that evil fellow over there. He raises the dead as his army. Oh by the way, I've returned from the dead too... Oops. Maybe I shouldn't have said that."

Comment: @Adwaenyth - "Brown eyes!  I still have brown eyes!!"  "For the Watch!"